# Android: Interact with content view when navigation drawer is open

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer that is always open I am doing it as follows:

```
mDrawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);
mDrawer.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

But now I want to intetract with the content view when the navigation drawer is open. When I tap a button on the content view nothing happens. How to interact with the content view when the navigation drawer is open?

Answer (score 1):

Navigation drawers are not made for that. You can make your own custom fragment and animate it like a drawer.